# Is insert intention lock a special type of gap lock, and can co-exist?

Tags: mysql, innodb

In [MySQL document, 15.7.1 InnoDB Locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html), it indicates that

> Gap locks in InnoDB are “purely inhibitive”, which means that their only purpose is to prevent other transactions from inserting to the gap. **Gap locks can co-exist**

> **An insert intention lock is a type of gap lock** set by INSERT

It confuse me a lot, if insert intention lock is a gap lock, gap lock can co-exist, so **insert intention lock and gap lock could co-exist**?

However, the practical result is that the gap lock and insert intention lock are conflict.

```
create table locker (
    pk int not null auto_increment, 
    some_key varchar(10) not null, 
    some_val varchar(25) default 'hello', 
    primary key (pk), 
    key idx_locker (some_key)
); 


insert into locker values (10, 'one', 'some-value'),
                          (20, 'two', 'some-value'), 
                         (30, 'three', 'some-value');
```

Session 1:  it will lock gap `(three, two]`

> select * from locker where some_key = 'two' for update;

Session 2: Blocked!

> insert into locker values (21, 'twa', 'some');

An odd thing is that there is no waiting if we perform the above steps in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

The precise lock mode compatibility is summarized in the following matrix (used to checks if a lock request `lock1` has to wait for request `lock2`.

| Lock 1 (new) \ Lock 2 | Gap lock | Record lock | Next-key lock | Insert Intention |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gap lock | Compatible | Compatible | Compatible | Compatible |
| Record lock | Compatible | ***Conflict*** | ***Conflict*** | Compatible |
| Next-Key lock | Compatible | ***Conflict*** | ***Conflict*** | Compatible |
| Insert Intention | ***Conflict*** | Compatible | ***Conflict*** | Compatible |

`Compatible` represents no waiting

**Rules**

1. Gap lock (not Insert Intension) do not need to wait for anything
2. Record Lock (including next-key) does not need to wait for a gap type lock
3. Lock on gap does not need to wait for Record type lock
4. No lock request needs to wait for an Insert intention lock to be removed
5. Need to wait in all other cases

Note: As Insert Intension is a type of gap lock, based on rule 3: it does not need to wait for a Record type lock.

Comment: Rule 3 is a little bit ambiguous: Does "lock on gap" means both Gap Lock and Insert Intention Lock? Does "record type lock" mean both Record Lock and Next-key Lock? If they are true, it does make sense to say "Lock on gap does not need to wait for Record type lock".